# If $B_t$ is a standard brownian motion process, is $B_t^2 - \frac{t}{2}$ a martingale w.r.t. brownian motion?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, martingales

If I have that $B_t$ is a standard brownian motion process, is $B_t^2 - \frac{t}{2}$ a martingale w.r.t. brownian motion? I know that $B_t^2 - t$ is but can't see it for the latter.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
E(B_t^2-\frac t2 \Big|B_s)&=E((B_t-B_s+B_s)^2-\frac t2 \Big|B_s)\\
&=E((B_t-B_s)^2+B_s^2+2B_s(B_t-B_s)-\frac t2 \Big|B_s)\\
&=t-s+B_s^2-0-\frac t2 \\
&=B_s^2-\frac s2+\frac {t-s}2 \\
& \geq B_s^2-\frac s2
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, @Math-fun. I think you have a typo in the second line after expanding the $((B_t - B_s) + B_s)^2$ term. It should be $(B_t - B_s)^2 + B_s^2 + 2B_s(B_t-B_s)$. Turns out not to affect the rest of the computation because the term with the typo has expectation 0.

Comment: @BillDeRose thank you :-) just fixed.

Comment: Not sure any of this is necessary since the OP knows that $B_t^2-t$ defines a martingale.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not. Just calculate the conditional expectation. It is a submartingale.